# The difference between this.method and super.method in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have BaseClass and InheritClass like this

```
export class BaseClass {
  public getDevice() {
  }
}

export class InheritClass extends BaseClass {
  constructor {
    super();
  }
  public devices() {
   // this.getDevice() // work in Nextjs project but undefined in Expressjs project
   // super.getDevice() // work both
  }
}
```

Can you explain why?
I'm using typescript.

tsconfig.json in Express project

```
"target": "ES2018",
"module": "commonjs",
"lib": ["es6", "dom"],
```

tsconfig.json in Nextjs project

```
"target": "esnext",
"lib": [
  "dom",
  "dom.iterable",
  "esnext"
],
"module": "esnext",
```

Below are codes in my project with Express

```
import { injectable } from 'inversify';
import "reflect-metadata";
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";
import rateLimit from 'express-rate-limit';
import { ResponseData } from "@/interface/responseData";
import { generalMsg } from "@/msg";

@injectable()
export class BaseMiddleware {
  private limiter = rateLimit({
    windowMs: 1 * 60 * 1000, // giới hạn 1 phút
    max: 1000, // tối đa 1000 requests trong 1 phút
  });
  public async execute(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void | {}> {
    try {
      this.limiter(req, res, () => {
        next();
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
  protected badRequest(error: {details: any}, res: Response){
    const responseData = new ResponseData(
      null,
      generalMsg.error.request,
      false,
      error.details
    );
    return res.status(400).json(responseData.toJson());
  }
}

import "reflect-metadata";
import { injectable } from "inversify";
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";
import Joi from "joi";
import { BaseMiddleware } from "@middleware/base.middleware";

@injectable()
export class DeviceMiddleware extends BaseMiddleware {  
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  public async addDevice(
    req: Request,
    res: Response,
    next: NextFunction
  ): Promise<void | {}> {
    try {
      const schema = Joi.object({
        userId: Joi.number().allow(null),
        deviceToken: Joi.string().required(),                
      });
      const validateSchema = await schema.validateAsync(req.body);
      next();
    } catch (error: any) {
      if (error) {
        return super.badRequest(error, res);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please take a look on `badRequest` method.

Comment: Here there is no difference, but if you had  `getDevice` in `InheritClass`,  `super.getDevice` would refer to `BaseClass.getDevice`, and `this.getDevice` would be `InheritClass.getDevice`

Comment: @Keith It is just example. I used once this.getDevice or super.getDevice only. I'm not using them together

Comment: All of the semantics come from JavaScript classes. I'm going to make a guess that you're Express project is being compiled to es5 and may also be using an old version of typescript. As it's a server-side project you can choose the node version you want to run and compile your code to es6 or higher.

Comment: You need to understand the basic of inheritance. `super.method` refers to the method that belongs to the `BaseClass` in this case and `this.method` refers to the method that belongs to the `InheritClass`

Comment: @AluanHaddad I update the question with tsconfig. Can you take a look?

Comment: @VNVNA I understand this

Comment: Thanks for the added information but I didn't even realize that NextJS isn't using TypeScript or Babeljs to transpile anymore apparently, so none of my knowledge applies

Comment: So are you asking why  `this.getDevice()` not working in an express app?.  There is no reason, we maybe need an example in express showing this.  Actually thinking about it, it was, it just returned undefined..

Comment: @Keith I update my question with project code using decorator

Comment: @HaiTien  Sorry, but how is the added express code related to the question you posted?.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is better visible if both classes have the `getDevice` method.

`this.getDevice()` will point to the child class while `super.getDevice()` will always point to the parent class.

```js
class BaseClass {
  getDevice() {
    return 'base';
  }
}

class InheritClass extends BaseClass {
  devices() {
    console.log(this.getDevice());  // inherit
    console.log(super.getDevice()); // base
  }
  
  getDevice() {
    return 'inherit';
  }
}

const instance = new InheritClass();

instance.devices();
```

Answer (score 0):

this depends on exactly what you use
super is like asking for parent

So if you have 2 classes

```
class Parent
{
    sayHi()
    {
        console.log('Hi');
    }
}

class Child extends Parent
{
    sayHi()
    {
        console.log('Yo');
    }

}
```

You can call both by it self since kids learn from parent's everything thats not private or protected from them
super.someMethod(); or extend parent and add something extra to it

```
const person = new Child();
person.sayHi();
//Output:
//'Yo';

person.super.sayHi();
//Output:
//'Hi'
```

Also your child class can do same as parent but with extra things like

```
class Child extends Parent
{
    sayHi()
    {
        super.sayHi();
        console.log('Whats up?');
    }

}

const person = new Child();

person.sayHi();
//Output:
//'Hi
//Whats up?'
```

Answer (score -1):

this.getDevice(): This refers to the getDevice() method of the current class, which is InheritClass. When you invoke this.getDevice(), it looks for the getDevice() method defined within InheritClass itself. If getDevice() is not defined in InheritClass, it will search for the method in the parent classes until it finds the method or reaches the top of the inheritance hierarchy.

super.getDevice(): This refers to the getDevice() method of the parent class, which is BaseClass. When you invoke super.getDevice(), it directly calls the getDevice() method of the parent class, bypassing any potential method overrides in the current class (InheritClass). This allows you to explicitly access and invoke the method implementation from the parent class.